# Verifying that .Net 4.6.2 is installed

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell and working on a a project to write a deployemnt package for a particular MSI.

One of the tings that I want to add to this is validation that the prerequisites are installed prior to continuing.

The code below is what I have cobbled together. It fails  on the initial check.

This is what I am using to determine if .Net 4.6.2 is installed:

```
Get-ChildItem "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | % { $_ -ge 394802 }
```

If I run this on a system that does have .Net 4.6.2 Installed. I get a 'True' response.

When I try and wrap it in an IF statement, I get this error:

```
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "-like" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
At C:\Users\bconway.TILLSTER\Desktop\EI4 Updater PowerShell Script\prereq test.ps1:4 char:118
+ ... t-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | % { $_ -ge 394802 } -like 'True')
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

This is the code I have written:

```
#Check to see that .Net 4.6.2 is installed
#Get-ChildItem "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | % { $_ -ge 394802 }
If (Get-ChildItem "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | % { $_ -ge 394802 } -like 'True')
{
Write-Host "Confirmed that .Net 4.6.2 is installed!"
#LogWrite "Confirmed that .Net 4.6.2 is installed!"
}
else
{
Write-Host ".Net 4.6.2 is NOT installed! Aborting Update!"
#LogWrite ".Net 4.6.2 is NOT installed! Aborting Update!"
exit
}
```

As always, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `-like 'True'`? Simply leave that out. The result of the expression *is* a boolean. (It would actually work, if you added an extra pair of parentheses to fix the operator binding, but it would still be unnecessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove `-like 'True'` as it's the source of your error as mentionned in the error message.

You can also simplify your code :

```
Get-ChildItem "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | ForEach-Object {
    switch ($_ -ge 394802) {
        $true  { Write-Host "Confirmed that .Net 4.6.2 is installed!" }
        $false { Write-Host ".Net 4.6.2 is NOT installed! Aborting Update!"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use a switch like this..?

Comment: Why not using it?

Comment: Well - It kinda worked :-) In need to make this backwards compatible to Powershell 2.0 - Is there a different approach that will do the same thing for older powershell versions?

Answer (score 0):

Add parentheses

```
If ((Get-ChildItem "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | % { $_ -ge 394802 }) -like 'True')
```

'-like true not needed' as Jeroen Mostert pointed out

```
If (Get-ChildItem "hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\" | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Release | % { $_ -ge 394802 })
```

You can skip Get-ChildItem cmdlet

```
If ("Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'hklm:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\' -Name Release" -ge 394802){}
```